# Use one search box to search for different items in the database

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

I have a search box that searches for a students name from the database.

I would like to use the same search box to display all students in the same class. For example;

What I have ;

When a user inputs a name say, fidel, students with the name Fidel are displayed.

What I want;

A user to input class on the same search box say, 5, and all students in class 5 will be displayed.

This is the method that searches for the student by name :

```
public function PostIndex()
    {
        $name = Input::get('name');

        $validator = validator::make(
            array(
                'name'=>$name
            ),

            array(
                'name'=>'required',
            )
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator);
        }else{
            $students=DB::table('students')->where('name', $name)->paginate(50);
        }

        if (count($students)) {
            return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));
        }else{
            Session::flash('fail', 'Sorry, no results found...');
            return view('admin.students.index',compact('students'), ['FailMessage' => 'Student by that name not found..'])->withHouse($students);
        }
    }
```

What is the logic behind using one search box to search for various items in the database?

This is my table:

```
id  | name |   adm  |  class  |  term  |  fees  |  created_at  |  updated_at
1     Martin   123     5          1        12      1.1.1           1.1.1
2     John     345     5          1        12      1.1.1           1.1.1
```

Comment: You have to use multiple where conditions on all the columns in the same query that you want the search to work on.

Comment: Assuming I want to search for all students in class 5; will I validate class as I have validated name(refer to my PostIndex())? then add ->where('class', $class) in my query?

Comment: Something like this is what i mean, DB::table('students')->where('name', $search_text)->orWhere('class', $search_text)->paginate(50);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of various different queries you can use the search box value and query something like this:

```
DB::table('students')
 ->where('name', $search_text)
 ->orWhere('class', $search_text)
 ->paginate(50);
```

The number of where conditions will be according to the columns you want the search result to be based on.
Also you can use 'LIKE' for text columns which will give you better results.

For your validation part, you can rename your input from 'name' to 'search'. You won't need two different input controls. Just one search box, and use the same variable for all columns.

Your new code would be something like this,

```
public function PostIndex()
    {
        $search_text = Input::get('search');

        $validator = validator::make(
            array(
                'search'=>$search_text
            ),

            array(
                'search'=>'required',
            )
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return back()->withErrors($validator);
        }else{
            $students=DB::table('students')->where('name', $search_text)->orWhere('class', $search_text)->paginate(50);
        }

        if (count($students)) {
            return view('admin.students.index', compact('students'));
        }else{
            Session::flash('fail', 'Sorry, no results found...');
            return view('admin.students.index',compact('students'), ['FailMessage' => 'Student by that name not found..'])->withHouse($students);
        }
    }
```

Comment: in this case should I replace the variable $search_text with $name and the second $search_text with $class?

Comment: No, you can use the same variable for both where conditions, assuming you want a single search box.

Comment: using the same variable would mean I would use $name in both where conditions, but I want to search for students in the same class as well, for example class 5; refer to my table structure.

Comment: You mean you search  '5'  and get results as records of martin and john right?

Comment: If you try the code in my answer, if your search 'martin' you will get record with id 1, if you search 5 you will get records with id 1&2

Comment: It's working thank you. Just for clarity, that code means when a user inputs 5, the query will look for student names in class 5, right?

Comment: Yes. It searches in both columns, name and class at the same time. Please accept if it worked for you.